# How to display nopcommerce plugin views in frontside after registration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, nopcommerce

I make nopCommerce sms plugin.

I know about entity insert of customer event in plugin. but i didn't get call in plugin after customer register.

I want to open one view page after customer registration from the plugin. Please give me some idea. Thanks in advance

Regards,

Jatin

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to redirect the users to another page after successful registration, you should use ActionFilter instead. Try this article I've written: [Overriding (Intercepting) NopCommerce Controllers And Actions](http://www.pronopcommerce.com/overriding-intercepting-nopcommerce-controllers-and-actions)